# How to configure powershell for OpenSSH instead of cmd

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, openssh, sshd

I have a Windows 10 Pro machine that I can `ssh` into (OpenSSH Server is installed/running) as `cmd`.  I want to have the shell as `powershell.exe` (not the default of `cmd.exe`).

I tried setting the following in `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd` per [this article](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/04/setup-powershell-ssh-remoting-in-powershell-6/), followed by `Restart-Service sshd`, but this doesn't work:

```
Subsystem   powershell  c:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -sshs -NoLogo -NoProfile
```

Nor does this work:

```
Subsystem   powershell  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -sshs -NoLogo -NoProfile
```

I have confirmed `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` to be the correct location of PowerShell.

How can I get the shell to be PowerShell for `ssh`ing into a Windows host?

Comment: "I have tried many other things," - what other things? This statement is pointless without details and doesn't help anyone including you. "this doesn't work" is also missing details, describe the exact **result**, not what is already known as you're asking for help.

Comment: You're using an article from 2019 that is no longer valid. PowerShell is at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and not in `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6`. Anyway, all you need to do in CMD is to enter the command `powershell` and you're there.

Comment: I deleted the "tried many other things", sorry.  And I know that article's path is incorrect, please see the OP for the paths I have tried @harrymc.  Also, thank for suggestion on just entering `powershell` to get there, good point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Subsystem` is not meant to change your default shell, quite the opposite – it defines a command that clients have to explicitly request. (It's literally a server-side alias.)

So the configuration snippet you found *wasn't meant* to change what you get from regular `ssh`; it's meant to allow a local PowerShell instance to invoke the SSH client and start a remote PowerShell on the server, without having to know its path (all it needs to specify is the subsystem name).

Specifically, the `-sshs` option indicates that it's meant for [**PSRemoting** over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.3) using the `Enter-PSSession` or `Invoke-Command` cmdlets, which can run via SSH in PowerShell 7.

```
PS> Enter-PSSession -HostName otherpc
[otherpc] PS>
```

(`-HostName` option makes it use SSH, whereas `-ComputerName` makes it use WinRM.)

(This won't work in PowerShell 5 – its PSRemoting support can only run [via WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/winrmsecurity?view=powershell-7.3), though if you want PowerShell then WinRM is actually not a bad alternative to SSH.)

---

Actually changing the default shell in Windows OpenSSH (the official Microsoft builds) is done completely differently – it's [documented on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#configuring-the-default-shell-for-openssh-in-windows):

```powershell
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" `
                 -Name DefaultShell `
                 -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" `
                 -PropertyType String `
                 -Force
```

Comment: Worked, thank you so much for spelling it out for me